# How to modify get_the_excerpt() when post-format equals 'quote'?

Tags: functions, post-formats

How can I modify the `get_the_excerpt()` when the `post-format` of the post is set to `quote`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question in SE I already found the solution:

```php
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'get_custom_the_excerpt' );

function get_custom_the_excerpt($excerpt) {

    $post = get_post();
    $format = get_post_format( $post );

    // modify excerpt if it is a quote, for example set title as author 
    if ($format == 'quote') {
        $output = '<q>'. $excerpt. '</q>
                <p class="quoted">'.get_the_title().'</p>';
    } 

    // return excerpt without change
    else {
        $output = $excerpt;
    }

    return $output;

}
```

For details check [get_the_excerpt()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) and [get_post_format()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format).